Sequential definitions of continuity and related classes
It is well-known that the usual 'epsilon-delta' definition of continuity is equivalent to the sequential definition (assuming countable choice).  Less well-known is the sequential definition of uniform continuity:
a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is sequentially uniformly continuous if for any sequences $(w_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, $(v_{n})_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|w_{n}- v_{n}|=0$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|f(x_{n}-f(y_{n})|=0$.
Are there (nice) sequential definitions of related classes, like Lipschitz or similer concept?  I could not immediately find any.

The Lipschitz condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\le L |x-y|$ is so much easier than (uniform) continuity -- why do you want a sequential characterization?

@JochenWengenroth In short: the sequential definitions (but not the epsilon-delta ones) have interesting logical properties.   Not so short: reverse math is a research program where one identifies the minimal axioms needed to prove a given theorem of ordinary math.  There is a certain range of logical systems (hyperarithmetical analysis) that is very hard to capture; sequential definitions greatly help to zoom in on hyperarithmetical analysis.
